# Creating a variable that incorporates for lagged values in longitudinal panel data

Tags: stata

I have data concerning 1000+ households. Each household has 31 datapoints. The data contains, among others, a variable which indicates whether the household has made a purchase at a certain store. I want to create a dummy variable which gives a 1 whenever a household makes a purchase and remains 1 for the rest of the time period, for that specific household.

For example,

```
Household ID - Purchase - New variable
1 - 0 - 0
1 - 0 - 0
1 - 0 - 0
1 - 1 - 1
1 - 0 - 1

2 - 0 - 0
2 - 1 - 1
2 - 0 - 1
2 - 1 - 1
2 - 1 - 1
```

Now I tried using the following code,

```
//electronics purchase dummy durin the full time series
gen betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy=0
replace betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy=1 if Betaal_winkel_ykw>0 & !missing(Betaal_winkel_ykw)

levelsof HHID, local(levels)
foreach l of local levels {
   replace betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy=1 if L.betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy==1
}
```

However, Stata has some difficulties with working this code properly, since when I run this code it starts off with making a lot of 'changes' and consequently it remains computing something (which I do not know what) but it does not make changes anymore,

```
 . foreach l of local levels {
  2.    replace betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy=1 if L.betaal_winkel_ykw_dummy==1
  3. }
(71048 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
```

And this just keeps on going. What am I doing wrong? What code should I use to get the same results (because when I break the code whilst it is running it is properly adjusted in my dataset) but without the trouble of Stata endlessly computing nonsensical things.

Comment: You have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516025/how-to-convert-time-variable-in-stata) pending feed back. The basic rules of courtesy imply that you attend to that. See also this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The problem is yours, not Stata's. Your `replace` statement automatically implies a loop: the `foreach` loop implies a redundant repetition of the same calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names you use in your example are too long and cryptic for me to want to take a detailed view at your code. I provide example code based on the wording of your problem. Notice that no loops are needed!

I assume that you have some variable by which your panels are sorted, most likely a date variable. I'll call it in my example `order`.

Then all you need to do is check the value of a running sum, per panel, and create the new variable accordingly. If the running sum is > 0, then a purchase has taken place.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id purch newvar
1  0  0
1  0  0
1  0  0
1  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
2  1  1
2  0  1
2  1  1
2  1  1
end

*----- what you want -----

gen order = _n
bysort id (order) : gen newvar2 = sum(purch) > 0

list, sepby(id)
```

See `help by` if you are not familiarized with this basic construct.